# Better Merge Tool for Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a good external merge tool for tortoisesvn (I don't particularly like the built in Merge tool).  I use WinMerge for diffs, but it doesn't work with the three way merge (maybe a better question would be is there a way to force tortoisesvn to merge like tortoisecvs?)

[Edit]

After trying all of them, for me, the SourceGear is the one I prefer.  The way to specify the DiffMerge from sourcegear is:

> C:\Program Files\SourceGear\DiffMerge\DiffMerge.exe  /t1="My Working Version" /t2="Repository Version" /t3="Base" /r=%merged %mine %theirs %base

Comment: Diffmerge user interface is optimized to base file shown in the middle so the correct turtoiseSVN commands is: sgdm.exe  /t1="Mine" /t2="Base" /t3="Their" /r=%merged %mine %base %theirs

Comment: @KrisErickson: Hello Sir, could you possibly help me out with my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36157555/3287204) ? Thank you ... :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Take a look at [Sourcegear DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/). DiffMerge is the compare and merge tool from their Vault and Fortress products, but they make it available for free as a standalone tool. One noteworthy feature is that it allows diffing of entire directory trees.

**Edit:** While DiffMerge remains a free tool, it nags for registration with a popup at least once a day (since at least version 4.2). It also states in the popup:

> Select new features in future releases will also require registration,
>   but core features and fixes will be available to everyone.

Answer (score 46):

[Perforce Merge Tool](https://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools)

Even though Perforce is obviously not free the merge tool is. It's 100x better than the default TortoiseSvn one. To integrate with TortoiseSvn set the merge tool to:

> C:\Path-To\P4Merge.exe %base %theirs %mine %merged

Comment: While looking quite nice, this is thing weighs in at 90MB!

Comment: During install deselect the other options/clients: `Helix Visual Client, Administration Tool and Command-Line Client` and only install the `Merge and Diff Tool` ....and besides: what is 90 MB nowadays? After 10mins getting used to it, this tool is really helpful!

Answer (score 22):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) has been suggested a number of times to me.

Comment: I can't recommend this enough with just an upvote.

Comment: @Nate Why is that?

Answer (score 6):

I use [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) as a 3-way merge tool.  It does a decent job.

Comment: It really can do a decent job and has a nice clean interface. I use it as a merge tool with TortoiseSVN and it can almost always fix my conflicts automatically. (I've seen things like Conflicts: 450; Automatically resolved: 448)

Answer (score 6):

[Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html) is expensive, but great.  Handles 3 way merges on files or folders really well.  I find the way it displays diffs much more helpful than Windiff or P4's tool.

Answer (score 3):

[CompareIt](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3.htm) is good, I find using the command line interface for svn, that it merges more for me, where tortoise picks up on things and asks you.

Answer (score 0):

I like this one [SmartSynchronize](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsynchronize/index.html) which is free for non-commercial use