# Is there any way to get TortoiseSVN to show the context of a patch without applying it to a local checkout?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, patch

I've used other systems like Starteam in the past and patches created using that system show the entire source file. Seeing the whole source when analysing patches can often help identify potential issues with a patch.

So my question is this: Is there an easy way to get TortoiseSVN diff tool to show the patch in context (without manually applying the patch to a local checkout)? ..or is there an external tool that could be made to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maarten-sander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4210/maarten-sander)'s answer in [another question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371/better-merge-tool-for-subversion) suggested using [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/). This offers the option to create patch files with full context.